# Change default web-server used by Apache Ambari

Tags: apache, browser, jboss, jetty, ambari

I am using `Ambari-Server` version 2.4.1.0
When I ran the command `nmap -sV` then I found out that it uses `Jetty` as default web-server. 
I want `Ambari` to use `JBoss` as web-server.

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this or share a link which can help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use jboss directly, it's source code dependency.
You have to take the source code from [github](https://github.com/apache/ambari) and replace jetty dependencies with jboss to build your own version.